# comparing two filename arrays for differences

Tags: arrays, perl

below is my attempt and loading all filenames in a text file into an array and comparing that array to filenames which are in a seperate directory. I would like to identify the filenames that are in the directory and not in the file so I can then process those files. I am able to load the contents of the both directories succesfully but the compare operation is outputting all the files not just the difference.

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

```
use File::Copy;
use Net::SMTP;
use POSIX;
use constant DATETIME => strftime("%Y%m%d", localtime);
use Array::Utils qw(:all);
use strict;
use warnings;


my $currentdate = DATETIME;
my $count;
my $ErrorMsg = "";
my $MailMsg = "";
my $MstrTransferLogFile = ">>//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/Artiva/ARTIVA_Mstr_Transfer_Log.txt";
my $DailyLogFile = ">//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/Artiva/ARTIVA_Daily_Transfer_Log_" . DATETIME . ".txt";
my $InputDir = "//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/folder1/";
my $MoveDir = "//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/folder2/";
my $filetouse;
my @filetouse;
my $diff;
my $file1;
my $file2;
my %diff;

open (MSTRTRANSFERLOGFILE, $MstrTransferLogFile) or $ErrorMsg = $ErrorMsg . "ERROR: Could not open master transfer log file!\n";
open (DAILYLOGFILE, $DailyLogFile) or $ErrorMsg = $ErrorMsg . "ERROR: Could not open daily log file!\n";


#insert all files in master transfer log into array for cross reference
open (FH, "<//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/Artiva/ARTIVA_Mstr_Transfer_Log.txt") or $ErrorMsg = $ErrorMsg . "ERROR: Could not open master log file!\n";
my @master = <FH>;
close FH;
print "filenames in text file:\n";
foreach $file1 (@master) { print "$file1\n"; }
print "\n";

#insert all 835 files in Input directory into array for cross reference
opendir (DIR, $InputDir) or $ErrorMsg = $ErrorMsg . "ERROR: Could not open input directory $InputDir!\n";
my @list = grep { $_ ne '.' && $_ ne '..' && /\.835$/  } readdir DIR;
close(DIR);
print "filenames in folder\n";
foreach $file2 (@list) { print "$file2\n"; }
print "\n";

#get the all files in the Input directory that are NOT in the master transfer log and place into @filetouse array
@diff{ @master }= ();;
@filetouse = grep !exists($diff{$_}), @list;;

print "difference:\n";
foreach my $file3 (@filetouse) { print "$file3\n"; }

print DAILYLOGFILE "$ErrorMsg\n";
print DAILYLOGFILE "$MailMsg\n";

close(MSTRTRANSFERLOGFILE);
close(DAILYLOGFILE);
```

this is what the output looks like:

```
    filenames in text file:
    160411h00448car0007.835


    filenames in folder
    160411h00448car0007.835
    160411h00448car0008.835
    160418h00001com0001.835

    difference:
    160411h00448car0007.835
    160411h00448car0008.835
    160418h00001com0001.835
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't produce that output. Please show the code you're really having a problem with

Comment: This is what i am using the only thing that is not included are the directories.

Comment: `$InputDir` isn't defined. The code you show won't compile under `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`. Please provide a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: edited  to include everything

Comment: Thank you. Did my answer below not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you to do what you need. It stores the names of all of the files in `INPUT_DIR` as keys in hash `%files`, and then deletes all the names found in `LOG_FILE`. The remainder are printed

This program uses `autodie` so that the success of IO operations needn't be checked explicitly. It was first available in Perl 5 core in v5.10.1

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;
use feature 'say';

use constant LOG_FILE  => '//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/Artiva/ARTIVA_Mstr_Transfer_Log.txt';
use constant INPUT_DIR => undef;

chdir INPUT_DIR;

my %files = do {
    opendir my $dh, '.';
    my @files = grep -f, readdir $dh;
    map { $_ => 1 } @files;
};

my @logged_files = do {
    open my $fh, '<', LOG_FILE;
    <$fh>;
};
chomp @logged_files;

delete @files{@logged_files};

say for sort keys %files;
```

---

#### Update

After a lot of attrition I found this underneath your original code

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece 'localtime';

use constant DATETIME  => localtime()->ymd('');
use constant XFR_LOG   => '//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/Artiva/ARTIVA_Mstr_Transfer_Log.txt';
use constant DAILY_LOG => '//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/Artiva/ARTIVA_Daily_Transfer_Log_' . DATETIME . '.txt';
use constant INPUT_DIR => '//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/folder1/';
use constant MOVE_DIR  => '//CFVFTP/Users/ssi/Transfer_Logs/folder2/';

chdir INPUT_DIR;

my @master = do {
    open my $fh, '<', XFR_LOG;
    <$fh>;
};
chomp @master;

my @list = do {
    opendir my $dh, '.';
    grep -f, readdir $dh;
};

my %diff;
@diff{ @master } = ();

my @filetouse = grep { not exists $diff{$_} } @list;
```

As you can see, it's very similar to my solution. Here are some notes about your original

- Always use lexical file handles. With `open FH, ...` the file handle is *global* and will never be closed unless you do it explicitly or until the program terminates. Instead, `open my $fh, ...` leaves perl to close the file handle at the end of the current block
- Always use the three-parameter form of `open`, so that the open mode is separate from the file name, and never put an open mode as part of a file name. You opened the same file twice: once as `$MstrTransferLogFile` which begins with `>>` and once explicitly because you needed read access
- It is very rare for a program to be able to recover from an IO operation error. Unless you are writing fail-safe software, a failure to open or read from a file or directory means the program won't be able to fulfill its purpose. That means there's little reason to accumulate a list of error messages -- the code should just `die` when it can't succeed
- The output from `readdir` is very messy if you need to process directories because it includes the pseudo-directories `.` and `..`. But if you only want files then a simple `grep -f, readdir $dh` will throw those out for you
- The *block* form of grep is often more readable, and `not` is much more visible than `!`. So `grep !exists($diff{$_}), @list` is clearer as `grep { not exists $diff{$_} } @list`
- Unless your code is *really* weird, comments usually just add more noise and confusion and obscure the structure. Make your code look like what it does, so you don't have to explain it

Oh, and don't throw in all the things you might need at the start "just in case". Write your code as if it was all there and the compiler will tell you what's missing

I hope that helps

Comment: this works great...now i am guessing will need to pass the %files to an array so i can then loop thru and move those files?

Comment: @user4990635: There's no need to copy anything. My code already "loops through" the file names to print them. If you wrote the original code yourself then you should be able to work it out. But *please* don't declare all your variables in one big block at the top: they should be declared as *late as possible*. Look at how I've used `do` blocks so that `$dh`, `@files` etc. only exist for as brief a time as possible. And use `constant` to define constants. You have a bunch of file paths that don't change, and having those names in ALL_CAPITALS would really help to make your code clearer

Comment: yes thank you very much. i am learning a great deal from this feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First, use a hash to store your already-processed files. Then it's just a matter of checking if a file exists in the hash.

(I've changed some variable names to make the answer a bit clearer.)

```
foreach my $file (@dir_list) {
   push @to_process, $file unless ($already_processed{$file});
}
```

(Which could be a one-liner, but get it working in its most expanded form first.)

If you insist on your array, this looks much less efficient

```
foreach my $file (@dir_list) {
   push @to_process, $file unless (grep (/^$file$/, @already_processed));
}
```

(Again could be a one-liner, but...)